# Want option back to choose between running app in device or emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm learing Android programming with Eclipse. I use to run my applications in either my mobile device or the emulator and it usally pop up a window where I can select which to run, and last time a checked the option to always run this device, so now I can only run it in my mobile device! I just wonder how I could get back the window to uncheck this option to be able to choose between them again? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `eclipse` `Run Configurations` select you applicaiton, then on the right on the `Target` tab select the `Always prompt to pick device` radio button.

Comment: what do you mean? make sure you save the `RunConfiguration` and that you use that `RunConfiguration`.

Comment: I meant that despite the changes, it still only run the application in the mobile device, but after a restartet Eclipse it's working as I want with the option to select between the two! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Same here. Looks like a bug in ADT. I'm using ADT v.20.